# How can I return indexed two-dimensional array from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, decode, encode, indexed

I need to return indexed two-dimensional array from PHP to JavaScript. I have been searching for solution for days. On client side I have on-change event (in option select) calling JavaScript function which executes a php file. This php file creates a 2 dimensional array from csv file, encodes that array with json. However, when I try to access elements of the array in JavaScript it gives me "undefined".
HTML file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var d;
function sendIt() {
if (d) document.body.removeChild(d);
var xmlhttp;
var state=arguments[0].options[arguments[0].selectedIndex].value
d = document.createElement("script");
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) //ready
          {
            document.getElementById("arrayresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.arrayFromPhp;
          }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","recordsbystate.php?state=" + state,true);
xmlhttp.send();
    d.type = "text/javascript";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="state" onChange="sendIt(this)">
    <option selected="selected">Select State</option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="CO">CO</option>
    <option value="MA">MA</option>
    <option value="TX">TX</option>
    </select>
    <div id="arrayresult"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP file:

```
$file = 'event_submission.csv';
$data2DArray = array();
$state = $_REQUEST['state'];
echo($state), "\n\n";
//create table with header and column names
print('<table align="left" width="430">');
print('<tr><th colspan="4">AOM DAY 2014</th></tr>');
print('<tr><th>Company</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Event Date</th><th>Event        Details</th></tr>');
$delimiter = ",";
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        $i = 0;
        while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
          if ($lineArray[7] == $state) {
            for ($j=0; $j<count($lineArray); $j++) { 
                $data2DArray[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j];
                }
       print('<tr><td>'.$data2DArray[$i][0].'</td><td>'.$data2DArray[$i][6].'</td><td>'.$data2DArray[$i][7].'</td><td>'.$data2DArray[$i][10].'</td></tr>');
          } 
            $i++; 
        } 
        fclose($handle); 
    } 
   $json = json_encode($data2DArray);
   echo 'var arrayFromPhp = ' . $json . ';';
   return true;
?>
```

Any suggestions? Please help....

Answer (score 1):

You're not really returning JSON. When you do `echo 'var arrayFromPhp = ' . $json . ';';`, it's no longer valid JSON, just echo the JSON without the other crap and convert it on the clientside to an object.

In PHP do

```
$json = json_encode($data2DArray);
echo $json;
```

and in javascript you'd do

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

    document.getElementById("arrayresult").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

}
```

to parse the JSON to a javascript object, you'd use

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

    var obj = JSON.parse( xmlhttp.responseText );

    document.getElementById("arrayresult").innerHTML = obj.someKey;

}
```

but note that innerHTML expects a string, not an object.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Trying to use 
json.parse( xmlhttp.dataArray ), but it's giving me a "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"